# Getting rid of all the errors in the Stack Program

Tags: c, stack, valgrind

valgrind output:

```
$ printf "push $RANDOM\npush $RANDOM\npush $RANDOM\npop\nprint\n" | valgrind --leak-check=full ./stacknode
==10735== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==10735== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10735== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==10735== Command: ./stacknode
==10735==
==10735== error calling PR_SET_PTRACER, vgdb might block
[0] = 19620
[1] = 30170
[0] = 19620
[1] = 30170
==10735==
==10735== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10735==     in use at exit: 738 bytes in 9 blocks
==10735==   total heap usage: 15 allocs, 6 frees, 8,994 bytes allocated
==10735==
==10735== 18 bytes in 3 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==10735==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10735==    by 0x4ED9A09: strndup (strndup.c:43)
==10735==    by 0x108A4D: stack_push (in /home/fathima1997/projects/Homework2/stacknode)
==10735==    by 0x108BF4: main (in /home/fathima1997/projects/Homework2/stacknode)
==10735==
==10735== 720 bytes in 6 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==10735==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10735==    by 0x4EBBB8B: getdelim (iogetdelim.c:62)
==10735==    by 0x108B77: main (in /home/fathima1997/projects/Homework2/stacknode)
==10735==
==10735== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10735==    definitely lost: 738 bytes in 9 blocks
==10735==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10735==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10735==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10735==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10735==
==10735== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10735== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Source code:

```
/*
 * Search this source code for a comment with XXX. You must
 * implement this missing functionality. When you run the program
 * input should look like any of the following:
 *    push hi
 *    push whoah
 *    pop
 *    print
 *    push tho
 *    print
 *
 * I will execute something like the following and check that valgrind
 * reports no errors.
 *
 * In my shell:
 * $ printf "push $RANDOM\npush $RANDOM\npush $RANDOM\npop\nprint\n" | valgrind --leak-check=full 
   ./stack
 */

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char* value;
    struct node* next;
};

struct stack {
    struct node* root;
    int length;
};

struct stack*
    stack_create(void)
{
    struct stack* r;

    r = malloc(sizeof * r);
    if (r == NULL)
        return NULL;

    r->root = NULL;

        return r;

}

/*
 * XXX: You must implement this function. It should remove
 * the top item on the stack and free the memory of both
 * the value and the node that was removed.
 */
void
stack_pop(struct stack* stack)
{
    /*
    assert(stack != NULL);
    assert(stack->root > 0);
    (stack->root)--;
    */

    if (stack->root == NULL){
        printf("You can't pop from an empty stack");
}
    else {
        struct node* top;
        top = stack->root;
        stack->root = top->next;
        free(top);
        return;
    }

}

bool
stack_push(struct stack* stack, const char* value)
{
    struct node* node;

    node = malloc(sizeof * node);
    if (node == NULL)

        return false;

    node->value = strndup(value, strlen(value) - 1);

    node->next = stack->root;
    stack->root = node;
        return true;
}

void
stack_print(struct stack* stack)
{
    struct node* cursor;
    size_t i = 0;

    for (cursor = stack->root; cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor->next)
        printf("[%zu] = %s\n", i++, cursor->value);

    return;
}

void
stack_destroy(struct stack* stack)
{
    struct node* cursor, * next;
    for (cursor = stack->root; cursor != NULL; cursor = next) {
        next = cursor->next;
        free(cursor);
    }
    free(stack);

    return;
}

int
main(void)
{
    struct stack* stack;

    stack = stack_create();

    for (;;) {
        char* token;
        char* line = NULL;
        size_t length = 0;
        ssize_t r;
        const size_t push_l = strlen("push ");

        r = getline(&line, &length, stdin);
        if (r == -1)
            break;

        if (strncmp(line, "push ", push_l) == 0) {
            line += push_l;

            if (stack_push(stack, line) == false)
                fprintf(stderr, "Stack push failed.\n");
        }
        else if (strcmp(line, "pop\n") == 0) {
            stack_pop(stack);
        }
        else if (strcmp(line, "print\n") == 0) {
            stack_print(stack);
        }
        else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unknown command: must be one of push, pop and print.\n");
        }
    }

    stack_print(stack);
    stack_destroy(stack);

    return 0;
}
```

***When I run this program I am getting these 2 errors, and I don't know how to get rid of that error. Can someone please help me?***

HINT: 
stack->root is a pointer, not an array or something.
If stack->root has value X (in other words, is a reference to an object stored in (X). X.next contains the next node so stack->root should be pointing to X.next.

Comment: The comment given to you in `stack_pop` tells you what to do: `free the memory of both the value and the node that was removed`. Review your code - have you done what the comment says?

Comment: Hint: Compile with `-ggdb` to get the line numbers in your source files provided in the stack traces

Comment: @kaylum Yes, The Program is compiling the good and I am getting the expected output. I just have to make the Valgrind have 0 errors.

Comment: @FathimaReeza My point is that your `stack_pop` implementation does not do "free the value" as instructed by the comment. You freed the node but not the value which results in mem leak and that is one of the ones valgrind tells you about. You need `free(top->value)` before `free(top)`.

Comment: @kaylum oh Okay got it! So when I free the value, it's giving me an another error.

Answer (score 0):

1)  Check the manual page for getline() -- you need to free the buffer.   You are setting it to NULL on each iteration of your for loop; you would be better to code it as:

```
char* line = NULL;
size_t length = 0;
while (getline(&line, &length, stdin) >= 0) {
...
}
if (line) free(line);
...
```

as the idiomatic forever loop is best applied when there are multiple loop exit conditions, or it really never exits.

2) in stack_pop() and stack_destroy() you free the node without freeing *value* -- the string created with strndup().   Why not just strdup() btw; it is more clear and precise.

Comment: `strdup(value)` is _not_ equivalent to `strndup(value, strlen(value) - 1);`. Which one of both is indeed the intended behaviour is another question, however.

Comment: But it's is doing the job tho. My program is compiling correctly and giving me the correct output @Ctx

Comment: Your program has memory leaks; that is what valgrind is reporting on.   If you don't care about leaks; don't run valgrind, or ignore its leak reporting.

Comment: I do have to check for leaks and make it error free. So that's why im trying to figure it out how to get rid of the error that the "getline()" is causing @mevets

Comment: OK, I identified three leaks your program has.  Even if you don't believe me, you could try the suggestions, and see if your valgrind output improves.   It is likely more productive than attempting to discuss it over a communication medium akin to a 1908 telegraph.

Comment: every time you call getline with a NULL value in *line*; that is every iteration of your big for loop, you are leaking the buffer from the previous call to getline.   Read the manual page, it says this.   If the system you are using doesn't say this, get another, they are cheap and there is no reason to put up with bad tools. Strn?dup is a little more obscure, but since it creates a new string, you might rightly infer that it is allocating it, and you need to free it.